Catholic Books in the Public Domain Whose Main Subject is the Magisterium (Teaching Authority of the Catholic Church)
I know that the term Magisterium is relatively recent---it refers to the Teaching Authority of the Catholic Church.
It seems that full length books (a few hundred pages or more) devoted to this topic are relatively rare; and moreover, I have not been able to find a single one written (in English) that is in the public domain in the United States.
There are some fairly recent ones such as Magisterial Authority by Fr. Ripperger, but it only contains 62 pages.
QUESTION: Can anyone point me to a book(s) devoted to the Magisterium of the Catholic Church that was (were) published in English prior to 1929? It seems to me that there should be some, but I have not yet discovered any.
Thank you.

Are you asking for a list of all imprimatured books?

You are unlikely to find many books on this topic published in English, especially as you go further back in time, since prior to the 20th century, the faithful generally simply accepted the authority of their bishops and pastors to teach the Catholic faith, and were not concerned with questions such as whether one teaching was infallible as dogma, infallible as intrinsically connected to dogma, or fallible yet to be assented to. Catholic laity were much more concerned with what they must do before Vatican 2.

@jaredad7 I have noticed that somewhere around the mid-nineteenth century, certain Catholic books came with an "Approbation" from the local ordinary. The term "Imprimatur" seems to have been introduced in the latter part of that century. As I suggested in a previous comment, it would ideal if I could locate such a book(s), but I would very much like to be aware if a reasonably sized book by a Catholic author devoted to the subject of the Divine Magisterium exists; and if so, if it is in the public domain that it might be re-typeset and republished.

@jaredad7 Such a book would also be, I think, beneficial to me as a Catholic, who is not immune to the plethora of fog and confusion that seems to be emanating from those who should be looking out for the flock and leading them to salutary waters instead of aggressively doing quite the opposite.
